# Mysql query taking more than 5 minutes having 19.1 M records

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, query-optimization

I am using Ubuntu server version 20.04

Configuration is 16GB RAM with 2 GB swapping facility.

I have 19.1 M records in my session table:

```
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| count(*) | min(session_id) | max(session_id) |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 19168798 |               6 |        19170401 |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Here is my query:

```
  SELECT appid, country, COUNT(DISTINCT(uuid)) as total 
  FROM sessions 
  WHERE appid = (appids) 
    AND created >= (createdFrom) AND created <= (createdTo) 
  GROUP BY country 
  ORDER BY total DESC;
```

I already have Indexing on my ID, uuid and created column.
When I run query, it almost take 5 minutes to load data.

Here, is the my mysqld.cnf file content

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
# pid-file  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
# socket    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
# port      = 3306
# datadir   = /var/lib/mysql


# If MySQL is running as a replication slave, this should be
# changed. Ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmpdir
# tmpdir        = /tmp
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
# max_allowed_packet    = 64M
# thread_stack      = 256K

# thread_cache_size       = -1

# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP

# max_connections        = 151

# table_open_cache       = 4000

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
#
# Log all queries
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/query.log
# general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
# slow_query_log        = 1
# slow_query_log_file   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
# long_query_time = 2
# log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
# server-id     = 1
# log_bin           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
# binlog_expire_logs_seconds    = 2592000
max_binlog_size   = 100M
# binlog_do_db      = include_database_name
# binlog_ignore_db  = include_database_name
```

Result of `DESCRIBE sessions;`

```
  +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | session_id     | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | uuid           | varchar(60)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | userid         | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | appid          | int          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | mau_count      | int          | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | systemversion  | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | os             | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | language       | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | country        | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | appversion     | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | phonename      | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | devicemodel    | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | city           | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | state          | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | latitude       | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | longitude      | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | startdatetime  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | enddatetime    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | duration       | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | phonecarrier   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | created_at     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | updated_at     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | is_deleted     | int          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | created        | date         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | api_version    | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Result of `SHOW INDEXES FROM sessions;`

```
+----------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+----------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| sessions |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | session_id     | A         |    19169624 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| sessions |          0 | session_id     |            1 | session_id     | A         |    19169624 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| sessions |          1 | sessionUuid    |            1 | uuid           | A         |     2738517 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| sessions |          1 | sessionCreated |            1 | created        | A         |        5189 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| sessions |          1 | sessionCreated |            2 | applicationsid | A         |       25939 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| sessions |          1 | sessionCreated |            3 | country        | A         |      259048 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| sessions |          1 | sessionCreated |            4 | language       | A         |      383392 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| sessions |          1 | sessionCreated |            5 | uuid           | A         |     4792406 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+----------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

Result of `EXPLAIN` statement:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT appid,country, COUNT(DISTINCT(uuid)) as total FROM sessions WHERE appid = 111 AND created >= '2023-12-01' AND created <= '2024-02-07' GROUP BY country ORDER BY total DESC;
```

[image]

Please guide how can I make this query speedup and what should I need to change.

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) to find out what's wrong with it (probably some missing index).

Comment: @teapot418 I already checked it with. I am facing this issue since last 2-3 months so I tried all the majority things. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You did? Don't forget to include the output of EXPLAIN on the statement in your question then.

Comment: @ChiragLukhi you should also paste the output for `DESCRIBE sessions;`  and a `SHOW INDEXES FROM sessions;`

Comment: appid = (appids) AND created >= (createdFrom) AND created <= (createdTo) - WHERE do the items in brackets come from? count distinct(uuid) makes no sense since uuids are by definition distinct, also add table definition.

Comment: @IonuțStaicu I updated question with describe and indexes.

Comment: @P.Salmon its dynamic values, Like appsid= (all application ids of login users)
and createFrom will be starting date and createdTo will be ending date to filter data.

Comment: appsid= (all application ids of login users) isn't valid mysql please expand , you have only tagged mysql

Comment: @chiragluki you still haven't pasted the EXPLAIN output. EXPLAIN is meant for this kind of scenarios, that's why it is important.

Comment: @A.Darwin will update soon.

Comment: `DISTINCT` isn't a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT uuid)` to make code clearer.

Comment: @A.Darwin I have added result of EXPLAIN statement too.

Comment: Column(2) ``applicationsid`` of index ``sessionCreated`` - what column in table?

Comment: @ValNik applicationsid > I have renamed earlier to appid. so both are same.

Comment: @P.Salmon - `UUID` may not be a unique for this table, but for some other table.

Answer (score 0):

19.1 M records is quite a lot if you do not have matching indexes for the query. The only index that could be used is the one for `created` and that depends on what is the date range used in the query:

Try creating indexes which match the WEHRE-clause and the GROUP BY:

```
create index session_appid_created on sessions (appid, created, country)
```

or even

```
create index session_appid_created on sessions (appid, created, country, uuid)
```

Comment: Your second suggestion is "covering", but the OP has a covering index already.  So, there might not be any advantage of one over the other.  It will depend on whether the first column(s), namely `appid` vs `created` is more selective, as to which index will be slightly better.

Comment: @RickJames. Yes, it all depends on the data (how many appid's, range of the date).  As Chirag's sessionCreated-index did not have the appid, It would be worth a try.

Comment: Having both indexes would give the Optimize a chance to pick the one that is better.  (But don't get carried away with this advice; other issues may arise.)